# Как измерить текст в Document-е RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Привет всем.Как можно измерить ширину\высоту Document-а RichTextBox-a если в нем разные размеры шрифта.Всем заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: А зачем вам это, если не секрет? Не пытаетесь ли вы подменить layout manager велосипедом?

Comment: Нет,просто форма не такая большая.Используя для "тренера химических реакций",ну там индексы всякие которые должно быть ниже и меньше и так далее..В реакциях соединяется два вещества а то и больше для этого надо использовать еще richtextbox-ы чтоб красиво было,а очень раскидано будет смотреться очень неудобно

Comment: Не вполне понятно. А зачем вам тогда всё это делать внутри RichTextBox? У вас есть mock-up того, что должно получиться? Есть шанс, что вы пошли неправильным, слишком сложным путём.

Comment: Не хочу казаться грубым но нужно именно так по некоторым причинам.Вопрос задан конкретный.